# Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions

Tags: navigation, rrt, base-global-planner, ros-hydro, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm trying do implement a base_global_planner plugin with RRT algorithm, for that I'm using the ompl package. The code compiles with no errors, and I followed the steps for registering the plugin but when I launch move_base I get the following error:

```
[FATAL] [1405968490.244759123, 1.315000000]: Failed to create the rrt_planner/RRT_Planner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: Failed to load library /home/mateus/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librrt_planner.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/mateus/catkin_ws/devel/lib/librrt_planner.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN4ompl4base13SO2StateSpaceE)
```

The macro is set as:

```
 PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(rrt_planner::RRT_Planner, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
```

The xml file:

```
<library path="librrt_planner">
   <class name="rrt_planner/RRT_GlobalPlanner" type="rrt_planner::RRT_GlobalPlanner" base_class_type="nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner">
    <description>
       A implementation of a grid based planner using RRT
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

CMakeLists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rrt_planner)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  costmap_2d
  geometry_msgs
  nav_core
  nav_msgs
  pluginlib
  tf
  angles
)

find_package(
    ompl
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES rrt_planner 
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    roscpp
    costmap_2d
    geometry_msgs
    nav_core
    nav_msgs
    pluginlib
    tf
    angles
  DEPENDS system_lib ompl
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ompl_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(rrt_planner
   src/rrt_planner.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(rrt_planner
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${ompl_LIBRARIES}
)
```

The package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

rrt_planner
    0.0.0
    The rrt_planner package

```
<maintainer email="mateus@todo.todo">mateus</maintainer>

<license>TODO</license>

<buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
<build_depend>angles</build_depend>
<build_depend>boost</build_depend>
<build_depend>costmap_2d</build_depend>
<build_depend>eigen_conversions</build_depend>
<build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
<build_depend>nav_core</build_depend>
<!--<build_depend>ompl</build_depend>-->
<build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
<build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
<build_depend>tf</build_depend>

<run_depend>angles</run_depend>
<run_depend>boost</run_depend>
<run_depend>costmap_2d</run_depend>
<run_depend>eigen_conversions</run_depend>
<run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>
<run_depend>nav_core</run_depend>
<run_depend>ompl</run_depend>
<run_depend>pluginlib</run_depend>
<run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
<run_depend>tf</run_depend>

<export>
  <nav_core plugin="${prefix}/rrt_planner_plugin.xml" />
</export>
```

I could not detect any error in the above code. So I think that the problem may be related with a warning I get when running catkin_make. The warning is the following:

```
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
```

Is my assumption correct? If so how can I solve that warning?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187313/package-%22ompl%22-does-not-follow-the-version-conventions/) by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ratneshmadaan](https://answers.ros.org/users/12636/ratneshmadaan/) on 2015-03-22**:
I got a [WARNING] for the same (ompl isn't following the naming convention) while compiling https://github.com/ros-industrial-consortium/godel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you're receiving indicates that a symbol from the OMPL library couldn't be found. This usually means that you're not linking against OMPL correctly in your CMakeLists

Try linking against `${OMPL_LIBRARIES}` instead of `${ompl_LIBRARIES}`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mateus03](https://answers.ros.org/users/18781/mateus03/) on 2014-07-22**:
Thank you, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For historical reasons, the convention for the OMPL version is non-standard:
https://github.com/ros-gbp/ompl-release/blob/master/read_this_before_releasing

This was done so that we have unique version numbers and can release OMPL for ROS outside of the regular OMPL release cycle. In the meantime things have stabilized much more, so I think we could start adopting a standard version. That said, we should probably switch to the debian package for OMPL directly (although, even for indigo, that is a bit old now).

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2014-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-04-28**:
Issue [link](https://github.com/ros-gbp/ompl-release/issues/4) to github